# Why can't I style this link?

Tags: html, css

I am the worst developer in the world but I try. I can't even get this link to style probably. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

I created a link with a div

```
<div class="ny"><a href=http://nyapples.com>yayaya</a></div>
```

css

```
.ny a {font-size: 2em;}
```

Comment: What is the expected result? What goes wrong?

Comment: I can't tell there's anything wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/VHqHp/

Comment: the font size isn`t changing.

Comment: thanks for the fiddle. I`ll go back to my blog and look again. The problem may be on my blog there`s a custom css style sheet and sometimes you have to put custom in front of stuff.

Comment: @user820196 - Use Firebug or Chrome Console, right click on the element, select 'Inspect Element', and it should tell you what is effecting the element.

Comment: @user820196 - http://getfirebug.com/html

Comment: btw i think you also need to add quotes to the url.. `<a href="http://nyapples.com">yayaya</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is anything wrong.

All I can think of is an error in your browser or a conflicting CSS rule.

I would recommend using Chrome, right clicking and choosing `Inspect element` or using Firebug on Firefox, then the tool to select the hyperlink.

In both, once selected, look at what CSS rules are being applied and see if there is something taking preference over this rule.

Comment: I couldn't code without firebug, and it's easy to add elements to test your css in-situ instead of lots of back and forth to get it right

Answer (score 0):

if you're having problem with customizing the css, you may have another stylesheet overwriting your changes. try this:

```
.ny a {font-size: 2em !important;}
```

that should force it to take priority over other styling. with blogs where you're customizing something that you haven't done from scratch, that may be the easiest way to solve

Comment: You can do this to test if it's being overwritten, but it's not a good idea to do it as a solution. My experience with !important is it tends to spread, and soon ALL your rules are !important and you're back where you started.

Comment: good point, but for someone who's getting started or not as comfortable yet going through someone else's code (like a modified WP theme) it's a quick and dirty solution. At the very least it's a good test to see if that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a few things that are causing this to happen:

1. Farther down in this style sheet, you are applying another style whose rule over-writes this one.  As many other people here have suggested, inspect the element to see which rules are being applied to it the element.  Remember to keep your most generalized or generic rules at the top and your most specific rules at the bottom of your stylesheet file.
2. Farther UP in this style sheet, you're missing a terminating character like a semi-colon or closing curly brace.  This can be a pain in the ass to catch because it's not always immediately evident since some of the rest of the sheet will load instead of the whole thing just breaking.

Hard to say without seeing anything else, but your current markup and style are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is correct. You might need to recheck your CSS as other folks posted previously.

I also recommend you work with a CSS reset before using your own stylesheet. This can avoid any conflict from browser rules. I recommend: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ or http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/